How can I use multiple values to create sheet names when using a script to create multiple sheets from master sheet?
I have a list of students assigned to various test rooms, and each room has a different test. (Although there are duplicates.) I would like to create a separate sheet for each test room where the name of the sheet includes both the test name and room number. I found a Youtube video that showed me how to create a script to make multiple filtered sheets from a master sheet and name each sheet based on the filter criteria. When I used the script for myself I used the room numbers as the filter criteria, but I would like to know how I could adjust the script so that when it is naming each new sheet it includes the test name as well as the room number.
I have tried simply adding a column in the master list that concatenates the desired info and reading from there, and that works, but I am hoping there is a way to do it in the script directly. (That an absolute novice like me can understand, lol.)
Here is the script I have been using (for a similar set of data, but without test name):
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceWS = ss.getSheetByName ("PSAT9");

  const testLocations = sourceWS
    .getRange(2, 6, sourceWS.getLastRow()-1,1)
    .getValues()
    .map(tr => tr[0]);

  const uniqueTestLocations = [...new Set(testLocations)];
  const currentSheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(s => s.getName());

  let was;

  uniqueTestLocations.forEach(testRoom => {
    if (!currentSheetNames.includes(testRoom)){
      ws = null;
      ws = ss.insertSheet ();
      ws.setName(testRoom);
      ws.getRange("A2").setFormula(`=SORT(FILTER(PSAT9!A2:J, PSAT9!F2:F="${testRoom}"),4,1)`);

      sourceWS.getRange("A1:J1").copyTo(ws.getRange("A1:J1"));
    }
  }) 
}


Assuming that your room is in column 6 (F) and your location is in column 7 (G) you need only make some tweaks to the constant testLocations:

expand its range to include 2 columns instead of 1
Join the values from the two columns. I delimited with a dash - but you can tweak as you wish:

const testLocations = sourceWS
    .getRange(2, 6, sourceWS.getLastRow()-1, 2)
    .getValues()
    .map(tr => tr.join('-'));
Trigger from Sheet
Add this bit of script at the end of your script and it will install a menu item so you can run this from the sheet.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addMenu(
    // "⚙️ Custom Menu",
    "⚙️",
    [{ name: "Sync Sheet Names and Data",
       functionName: "myFunction" }]
  );
}



That worked very well, thank you so much!
